# Using Facebook OG Meta Tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I am integrating Facebook sharing on my site and am struggling to get the og meta tags to work properly. Currently when I click the share button a dialog opens but the info in the share dialog is not the info I specified in the meta tags. Instead the title is the page title, there is no image and the description is a paragraph on the page, shown below:

[image]

How can I get the info to be the info specified in the meta tags?

Here is the relevant html:

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:url" content="url" />
    <meta property="og:title" content="Dope Clothing" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="South African streetwear by South African streetwear lovers" />
    <meta property="og:image" content="Images/logo_thumbnail.png" />
</head>
<body>

    <div id="fb-root"></div> 
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '1471809223084795',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.1'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

<div id="share">
  <div class="share-box"><div class="facebook-share">f</div></div>
</div>
```

And the Javascript function that fires when the share button is clicked:

```
$('.facebook-share').click(function() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share',
        href: 'http://www.website.com/index.php',
        }, function(response){});
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using the Open Graph debug tool? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Comment: I just tried it now, it's not picking up  my meta properties for some reason

Comment: As well as that it sees my meta links that are in my head in my body ?!

Comment: I had the same issue some time ago and after i've added the '<meta property="og:type" content="website" />' tag everything went fine. I know that that's the default value – just give it a try...

Comment: Gave it a shot, still no luck :(